# Objective-C: NSMutableString replaceCharactersInRange raising Exception

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string

I expected this code to replace the hate with some love.

```
 NSMutableString *teststring=@"I hate programming my iPhone";

 NSString *overwriteSource=@"love";

 NSRange temprange=NSMakeRange(2, 4);

 [teststring replaceCharactersInRange:temprange withString:overwriteSource];

 NSLog(@"%@",teststring);
```

This terminates due to an uncaught exception and I can't figure out why. Help ! (and thanks)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your first line, you're attempting to assign an NSString * (@"I hate...") to an NSMutableString * (teststring).

Your original code should give you a compilation warning:

> incompatible Objective-C types
>   initializing 'struct NSString *',
>   expected 'struct NSMutableString *'

The following will allow your code sample to compile and run correctly:

```
NSMutableString *teststring=[NSMutableString stringWithString:@"I hate programming my iPhone"];
```

Comment: Many Thanks - (I don't get a compilation warning)